# Text in React-Circular-Progressbar not centered

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, progress-bar

I am struggling with getting the text to be centered when I create a circular progress bar.

This is the code where the progress bar and text is added.

```
<div>
  <ProgressBar
     value={80}
     text="80%"
     strokeWidth={5}
     styles={buildStyles({trailColor:"red"})}
  />
```

This code is the styled portion for the progress bar. Is it possible to center the text to the progress bar

```
const ProgressBar = styled(CircularProgressbar)`
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
`;
```

[This is what the progress bar currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PWgB.png)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're importing the css file.

```
import "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe we can utilize `flex` here.
On the container that contains the text's tag.
You can add.

```css
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Just make sure the text is direct child of the container that applied `flex` style that I mentioned before

Answer (score 0):

The only one method that works for me was that I transform x and y.

```
.CircularProgressbar-text {
    transform: translate(-15px, 5px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more cleaner way would be to use `text-anchor` property and `align-baseline` property on the `.CircularProgressbar-text`.

Example:

```
.CircularProgressbar-text {
text-anchor: middle;
alignment-baseline: middle;
}
```

This will solve your problem with aligning the text in the middle of the Progress Bar.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.CircularProgressbar-text {
   dominant-baseline: middle;
   text-anchor: middle;
}
```

Or you can import the following:

```
import "react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css";
```